wrong number of values in weka
can any one tell me what the wrong in this file the error massege is :
wrong number of values read w, expected 1, read token [eol], line 2 problem encountered on line:2
this is the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S6ruZJBRXMGMfcaueYSvKN1s5OXJwwHA/view?usp=sharing
i tried a lot of data cleaning ways like fill the empty cells and else
im waiting for your help thanks

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant details here as a [mcve].

Your CSV file contains multi-line cells, which Weka's CSVLoader does not handle, it requires new lines to be escaped as \n.
Instead, you can install and use the common-csv Weka package. The CommonCSVLoader can load this CSV file, when using the following options:

useCustomFieldSeparator: true
customFieldSeparator: ;

